# Recruiter said will call this afternoon

Tags: interviewing

Recruiter and I have been in contact since I interviewed with the regional manager. Had a phone interview, then interviewed with manager, and finally with regional manager. He said they needed to push back my start date and the regional manager was deciding the best way to onboard me. I touched based Tuesday and he said should have everything done tomorrow. Got email today finishing one last thing will call this afternoon. They wouldn't set all that up to say no, right?

Comment: Who knows? Wait and see if they call and offer you the job.

Comment: No. Unless something comes up, like a memo that lands in their Inbox within the next 15 minutes, and the memo mandates a hiring freeze effective immediately. As Yogi Berra used to say "It ain't over until it's over" :)

Comment: You don't have an offer in writing, do you? And even if you do, stuff happens. Keep in contact with that recruiter/company and keep looking.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about guessing a future result and has no actionable item to help with.

Answer (score 4):

This has happened to me, twice. I did eventually start with the company, both times. Delays were internal, they were all due to preparation for onboarding. (I am assuming you have an offer in writing from the recruiter, to work at that first company.)

The second time this happened to me, I kept looking for a job. My plan was that if I received another offer in writing before the first place actually got around to onboarding me, I would contact the recruiter, let him know that I'd received another offer with a start date of X, and while I really was excited to work for the first company...I really did need a firm commitment from that first company to start work (and getting paid full time) by that other start date, or I was regretfully going to have to accept this other offer. That would have sent the recruiter back to the hiring manager saying "Okay, we have to move on this now, it's urgent, the person really wants to work for you but it's down to needing to pay the bills now. Can you onboard this person already?" And then either the first company would have brought me onboard and paid me even if they weren't 100% ready, or I'd be able to start with the second company. Either way, I'd have a job and income.

My advice to you: keep following up with the recruiter, check in daily, let him know that you're really looking forward to starting with that first company....and keep looking for another job. You may not ever get as far as a second offer; and you'll more than likely be brought onboard to that first company. But this gives you an emergency backup plan, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds hopeful, but never count your chickens until they hatch.  You'd be surprised what can happen before they talk to you with an offer, there could be last minute changes that mean the role is on hold/no longer available, or you could really be second choice and first had bombed them out, then reconsidered.

The best thing is to put it out your mind until you hear one way or the other, most likely it'll be good news.

But don't give up on your other possibilities yet

Hope for the best, but plan for the worst.